# Is there a way to check if the record is using the default value for certain columns?

Tags: mysql, search, default-value

Suppose i have a table with an attribute named, lets say, 'Type' with default value 'A'.
I want to select the tables that use this default value 'A'. The obvious answer is ofc,

```
select *
from table 
where Type='A';
```

But I wanted to see if there was a more efficient way to do this. Maybe making use of the 'DEFAULT' constraint?

Comment: You mean something like `WHERE Type IS DEFAULT`? Without knowing or writing the default value?

Comment: Yes exactly. Wait will ```WHERE Type IS DEFAULT``` work? Edit: Nope nvm that didn't work.

Comment: I doubt that very much :-) - But if something like that were possible - this would likely be the syntax.

Comment: To partially answer your question: Yes - It's possible, but it's not "more efficient". You need to query the `information_schema`.

Comment: What's the purpose of more efficiency?

Comment: The purpose of question is pure curiosity. Thought it'd be a fairly common query and hence probably had a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but I think it's quite interesting and I can see that if this `WHERE Type IS DEFAULT` does exists, it is something useful.

Something dynamic; without needing to explicitly define the default value in `WHERE` condition.

I'm elaborating on Paul comment about querying the `information_schema` and the query might look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM example1 A INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT column_default 
         FROM information_schema.columns 
         WHERE table_schema='test' 
         AND table_name='example1') B
ON A.Val=B.column_default;
```

It's longer and instead of explicitly defining the default value, I had to define the table_schema and table_name; which turn out to be far from being dynamic. I've prepared a fiddle as well https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8idH1J7PnyvRwU8tQhyzMb/0

Comment: This definitely qualifies for the dynamic part but it still doesn't get past the need to compare the strings themselves. I think this would probably fail in the cases where the default itself is dynamic like for example a column that takes current date as default.

Comment: I was also thinking about the current date default value while trying to come up with this example. Truthfully, I would say it's the most defined default value whereby you'll definitely at some point will assign a column to current date as default. However, I don't think that in your case or attempt you'll expect to query any column with current date value as default because the `column_default` in `information_schema.columns` will have `current_timestamp` as default value instead of the date itself.. unless your default date value is fixed e.g '2020-01-01'

Comment: If only they also stored it as `current_timestamp` for every record using default somewhere internally...

Comment: I agree with you.. and I reiterate that it might come handy.. well, it seems like if it does it exist now, it will be very handy for your situation xD